# Какова причина, по которой меню верстают через ненумерованный список ul?

Tags: html, css

Какова причина, по которой меню верстают через ненумерованный список `ul`?

Не знаю "правильно" это или нет, но у меня получилось без всяких проблем сверстать нормально работающее одноуровневое горизонтальное меню в виде таблицы, а с помощью `flexbox` так и вообще замечательно всё верстается.

Comment: например потому, что таблицы, по задумке, должны были использоваться для вывода табличных данных, а не для организации расположения элементов.

Comment: А `ul` был задуман для вывода списков, а используется не только для меню, но и для слайдеров. Хорошо, а чем flexbox не привлекателен? Назначаем `dispaly: flex` контейнеру меню и внутри только ссылки `a`, которые ведуть себя как надо. Никаких лишних тэгов.

Comment: зачем тогда flexbox если вы используете таблицы? Можно одноуровневое меню сделать и просто дивами/ссылками/пунктами списков

Comment: @Василий Барбашев тэгов меньше будет и стилей тоже меньше. В таблице будет вложенность `table>tr>td>a`, да ещё `a` надо на всю высоту ячейки растягивать, а с `flexbox` только контейнер и ссылки внутри.

Comment: У многих просто семантика головного мозга. Делайте как нравится.

Comment: @GurebuBokofu не будет меньше, таблицы это всегда `table, tr, td, a`, а тут `div, a`, или `div, li, a`? Но на самом деле это все фигня, вы сами делаете для себя, просто если это будет использовать кто-то (не вы), ему надо будет разбираться почему именно так

Comment: @Василий Барбашев, исправил свой предыдущий коментарий.

Comment: Вы растянете `a`, растянется контейнер как вам надо, зачем таблицы?)

Comment: @mJeevas, с точки зрения СЕО верстка меню через ненумерованные списки действительно считается более правильным подходом. Почему? Дать ответ на этот вопрос не могу, но сеошники в моём отделе требуют именно такую реализацию.

Comment: @Игорь, как и Вас, у меня нет веских аргументов за или против `ul`, но если рассуждать чисто логически, то google-робот не настолько туп, чтобы не найти внутри `nav` ссылки и не понять, что это меню. Официальное руководство google по `seo` не даёт никаких рекомендаций в отношении способов вёрстки меню. Ваши специалисты SEO, как и любые другие не работающие в google специалисты, не могут иметь прямых доказательств влияния способа верстки меню на позиции выдачи в google.

Comment: @GurebuBokofu, не буду спорить что есть правильно, а что - нет. Тем не менее лично мне кажется использование списка в этих целях более логичным хотя бы потому что меню - все-таки ничто иное как именно список элементов :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Сначала для верстки таких меню действительно использовались таблицы потому что не было поддержки многих CSS-фич. Вообще все версталось таблицами. Со временем технологии развивались и таблицы потеряли свою актуальность в разметке страницы из-за того что таблицы сложно поддерживать.

Тогда была два актуальных варианта: обернуть ссылки в див, сделать список. Из этих двух подходов список более правилен с семантической точки зрения потому что меню — это как раз список ссылок.

В стандарте HTML5 появился тег nav, но, несмотря на это, [в спецификации](https://www.w3.org/TR/html5/sections.html#the-nav-element) рекомендуют использовать список для списка ссылок для упрощения понимания структуры навигации. Как-то так:

```css
nav {
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
}
nav ul {
  display: flex;
  width: 100%;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
nav li {
  border-right: 1px solid #ccc;
  flex-grow: 1;
  padding: 5px;
  list-style: none;

}
nav li:last-child {
  border-right: none;
}
```

```html
<nav>
  <ul>
    <li><a href="#">Пункт 1</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Пункт 2</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Пункт 3</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Пункт 4</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Пункт 5</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Пункт 6</a></li>
  </ul>
</nav>
```

Comment: Семантически правильно по-прежнему верстать списком, но уже внутри `<nav>`.

Comment: @Sasha Omelchenko, но не очень изящно для одноуровневых меню. Собственно, я этот вопрос задал из стремления к чистому HTML-коду типа "ни одного лишнего тэга". То, что показал Дмитрий и является идеалом с точки зрения минимизации тэгов для случая одноуровневого меню.

Comment: @SashaOmelchenko, я сейчас заглянул в спеку. Действительно, там говорят о том, что нужно использовать список: https://www.w3.org/TR/html5/sections.html#the-nav-element Я поправлю ответ

Comment: @Dmitry Shishkin, благодарю Вас за ответ и сбор информации.